# Android 2.2 have scrolling issues with phonegap app?

Tags: android, scroll, cordova, android-2.2-froyo

I have a phone gap app. 
When I test it out on 2.2 froyo, (on actual phone and in AVD) it refuses to scroll.

I've tested it out on 2.3.3 and it works perfectly. Are there issues with scrolling in the 2.2 version?

If so, is there a workaround to this?

Answer (score 0):

Some PhoneGap examples include the following line in initialization code:

```
document.addEventListener("touchmove", preventBehavior, false);
```

This will disable scrolling on some devices. If your app includes it, try deleting (or commenting) it.

Comment: i couldn't find that particular line....but i did find this in the PhoneGapActivity.java
I made the vertical scroll bar true as they were all false. 

super.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  super.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

  // set some defaults
  this.appView.setBackgroundColor(0x000000);
  this.appView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
  this.appView.setHorizontalScrollbarOverlay(false);
  this.appView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
  this.appView.setVerticalScrollbarOverlay(true);

Comment: when i set them to true, it worked in the AVD, but not an actual device. 
i'm still new to all of this - but learning a lot!